# Bar with negative stack in HighCharts to set Y axis max value on both sides

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to set max value for Y axis on both sides to 100.

Currently when the value is 100 , graph automatically expands to 125.

When I use max :100 in Y axis , this effects only on positive side not

on  negative side.

Comment: So, then set `min` to -100.

Comment: Set a minPadding / maxPadding parameters as 0 in the yAxis object.

Comment: set min to -100 worked ....cheers